# how to add n number of input fields in html using js

Tags: javascript, html

I have to get 'n' - total number of names from the user and then create n number of fields for getting all the names. I've currently written this as:

HTML code:

```
<form action="/flight_ticket/book" name="myform" method="post">
  .
  .
  .
  Enter the number of tickets to be booked:
  <input name="nooftickets" type="text"><br/><br/>
  <a href="#" id="names" onclick="addFields();">Enter names</a>
  <div id='container'/>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
function addFields(){
    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("nooftickets").value);
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
      container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i=0;i<number;i++){
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name " + (i+1)));
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      input.name = "name" + i;
      //input.required= true;
      container.appendChild(input);
      container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
```

But when I run it on browser, after clicking the "Enter names", I don't see any changes in the browser!
What have I got wrong?

Comment: Please, explain what's going wrong.

Comment: Just did, no change after clicking the "Enter names" hyperlink

Comment: what is the type of `number` , looks like it is a string and you might need to parse it to an int. `number = parseInt(number);`

Comment: I parsed to integer too, didn't have any effect

Comment: if you want to remove all the child inside the `container` then use `container.innerHTML=''` instead of looping. and you are trying to fetch the name instead of id. so replace the line for `document.getElementById("nooftickets").value` to this `document.getElementsByName("nooftickets")[0].value`

Comment: @vikscool thanks, that was the mistake, I accidentally forgot to set id for the input field

Comment: change this input attribute  'name' to' id'  **<input id="nooftickets" type="text">**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to fetch the value of the `noofticktes` which is defined as a `name` in the HTML but in your code, you are using `document.getElementById('noofticktes').value` which is throwing an `undefined` error as there is no `id` defined as `noofticktes`. 
So, just change your code on from:

```
var number = document.getElementById("nooftickets").value;
```

To this:

```
var number = document.getElementsByName("nooftickets")[0].value;
```

you will be able to make your code work.

One small update in your code would be if you are trying to clear/remove all the contents of the element `container` just use the `container.innerHTML=''` instead of looping and removing each element.

Here is the updated Snippet of your code.

```js
function addFields() {
  debugger;
  var number = document.getElementsByName("nooftickets")[0].value;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = '';
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name " + (i + 1)));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "name" + i;
    //input.required= true;
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="/flight_ticket/book" name="myform" method="post">
  . . . Enter the number of tickets to be booked:
  <input name="nooftickets" type="text"><br/><br/>
  <a href="#" id="names" onclick="addFields();">Enter names</a>
  <div id='container' />
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addFields() {
  // body...
  var input = '';
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  for(var i=0;i<number;i++)
  {
   input +="<input id='number"+i+"' name='number"+i+"'><br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = input;
  
 }
```

```html
<form action="/flight_ticket/book" name="myform" method="post">
  
  Enter the number of tickets to be booked:
  <input name="nooftickets" id="number" type="text"><br/><br/>
  <a href="#" id="names" onclick="addFields();">Enter names</a>
  <div id='container'/>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
</form>
```